# How do I validate and repair broken xml tags?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

```
<note>
     <to>ahmad</to>
     <from>jhon
     <body>hello how are you!!!</body>
</note>
```

Above is my xml file which has no ending tag for the `from` tag, which gives an error.
I need actionscript code to check if there is a broken tag and then fix it automatically.

Comment: this will only be possible if you have a very defined XML structure that you are importing. Are you trying to get a general "fixer" or do you have a specific application?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way you could do this is by analyzing the text of the XML document before attempting to convert it into an XML object. This really isn't ideal and it would be much better if you could validate the XML before attempting to bring it into Flash. You could possibly do this by using one of the many online [XML validators](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/) or [server side scripts](http://www.xml-training-guide.com/validate-xml-against-schema-using-php.html) to check the document. 
I also found this [implementation of a validator in AS3](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/708608) which might be useful.